# Domain bucket name taken Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I have a project on Google Cloud and I am trying to create a bucket to store my web files for my website. The only problem is I have a CNAME going from my website to 'c.storage.googleapis.com' so my bucket name has to be the same as my website name which is 'plains.cc'. When I try to create the bucket however, it says the name is already in use. I used this bucket name on a previous account but deleted it so I don't understand why I can't reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you still unable to create it? As per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#considerations), If you have deleted the bucket from your previous project then I guess this should be a timing issue. But if you have deleted the previous project directly without deleting the bucket contained within it, it could take more a month or more to get the associated data to be eventually deleted. Read document on this [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en).